# Git merge behavior (ahead of x by y commits)

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

I've came across Git behavior I cannot fully understand. The repo is used by tens of people. The case is like this:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --no-commit feature
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

    modified:   web/webapp/grails-app/views/layouts/empty.gsp

$ git commit -m 'commit message'
[master e6cc2eb] commit message

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 21 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

What confuses me is this part:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 21 commits.
```

How come it's not 1? Just make it clear, there was only a single change in that empty.gsp file.

There are actually 20 more commits, but why they do not show up after `git status`? Any hints what I might be missing?

Comment: Maybe there was just one change to the file empty.gsp but obviously there are 20 other commits.

Comment: Did the `feature` branch have 20 commits to `empty.gsp`? Of the 21 commits, one will be the merge commit, so the other 20 are from the `feature` branch.

Comment: @ckruczek yeah, there are 20 other commits with changes made in other files. why these don't show up in affected files?

Comment: @meliniak: Because they are not affected by any merge conflict.

Comment: @ckruczek empty.gsp file wasn't in conflict either?

Comment: @meliniak: Well obviously this one was affected by a conflict. Which was git able to handle automatically.

Comment: @ckruczek ok I will make a test for it and share the outcome. thanks so far.